# Is there any way to see make file with all variables substituted

Tags: ubuntu, shell-script, make, makefile

I have huge long `makefile` written by some other guy, where all coomands contain variables.

In order to decode what this command is doing i have look around what that variable is and its taking too much time.

is there any way to see the make makefile where all variables are automatically substututed or `dry running` so that i can see what each function is doing

Answer (score 2):

Try `make -p`: it shows you all rules that make knows about, at the end of parsing (which means after running all functions including $(shell), $(wildcard) and $(patsubst)). Beware, it will be very long, because it includes all the prebuilt implicit rules too, so you'll probably want to do `make -p | less` and then search through it.